# How to do summation of product of two input values from a clone table input values

Tags: jquery, sum

I am unable to do summation of the subtotal from the clone table input values.
Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rKjbg/

```js
var $to_clone = $('.tr_clone').first().clone();

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function () {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $to_clone.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_remove', function () {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    $tr.remove();
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity, .price", function(){
    var prtCont = $(this).parent().parent();
    var prce = parseInt(prtCont.find('.price').val()) - 0;
    var qnty = parseInt(prtCont.find('.quantity').val()) - 0;
    if(!isNaN(prce) && !isNaN(qnty)){
        prtCont.find('.subtotal').val(prce * (qnty));
    }else{
        prtCont.find('.subtotal').val("");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0"  >
<tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>U$ Price</td>
<td>Subtotal</td>
    <td>Add</td>
    <td>Remove</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_clone">
    <td>
        <select style="width:200px" name="itens[]">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Item A</option>
        <option value="2">Item B</option>
        <option value="3">Item C</option>
    </td>                                            
    <td><input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" name="qtd" class="quantity text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="price" class="price text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="subtotal" class="subtotal text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" class="tr_clone_remove"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Duplicating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498032/how-to-calculate-summation-same-id-of-two-products-from-cloned-input-values-jque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function `updateTotalOfSubTotal()` which should be called on every trigger that happens. In your case, its `keyup`. You can call `updateTotalOfSubTotal` at other triggers too.

Here is the updated code that would give you total of subtotal:

```js
var $to_clone = $('.tr_clone').first().clone();

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
  var $clone = $to_clone.clone();
  $clone.find(':text').val('');
  $tr.after($clone);
});

$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_remove', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
  $tr.remove();
  updateTotalOfSubTotal();
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity, .price", function() {
  var prtCont = $(this).parent().parent();
  var prce = parseInt(prtCont.find('.price').val()) - 0;
  var qnty = parseInt(prtCont.find('.quantity').val()) - 0;
  if (!isNaN(prce) && !isNaN(qnty)) {
    prtCont.find('.subtotal').val(prce * (qnty));
  } else {
    prtCont.find('.subtotal').val("");
  }
  updateTotalOfSubTotal();
});

function updateTotalOfSubTotal() {
  var totalPoints = 0;
  $(".subtotal").each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).val()))
      totalPoints += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $(".totalOfSubTotal").text(totalPoints);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>U$ Price</td>
    <td>Subtotal</td>
    <td>Add</td>
    <td>Remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr_clone">
    <td>
      <select style="width:200px" name="itens[]">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Item A</option>
        <option value="2">Item B</option>
        <option value="3">Item C</option>
    </td>                                            
    <td><input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" name="qtd" class="quantity text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="price" class="price text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="subtotal" class="subtotal text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" class="tr_clone_remove"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="totalOfSubTotal"></div>
```

Comment: Hi remove rows values are not updating

Comment: Thanks it working great. I have tried it more than two hours. Once again Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote and mark this as done.

Comment: Hi, Can you check this, what wrong with this code. https://jsfiddle.net/jvk3/6ath5vy9/4/