# How to calculate summation same id of two products from cloned input values jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

How to do each summation of class three of the products.

Here is my similar work.

[How to do summation of product of two input values from a clone table input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494914/how-to-do-summation-of-product-of-two-input-values-from-a-clone-table-input-valu)

```js
$("table").on("change", "input", function() { //use event delegation
  var tableRow = $(this).closest("tr"); //from input find row
  var one = Number(tableRow.find(".one").val()); //get first textbox
  var two = Number(tableRow.find(".two").val()); //get second textbox
  var total = one * two; //calculate total
  tableRow.find(".three").val(total); //set value
});

$("button.add").on("click", function() {
  var tbody = $("table tbody");
  tbody.find("tr:eq(0)").clone().appendTo(tbody).find("input").val("");
});

function updateTotalOfSubTotal() {
  var totalPoints = 0;
  var tableRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  var test = tableRow.find(".three").val();
  totalPoints += test;
  console.log(totalPoints);
}

updateTotalOfSubTotal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="one" /></td>
      <td><input class="two" /></td>
      <td><input class="three" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @mplungjan. I am trying sum of all class three

Comment: You mean  `var total = 0; $(".three").each(function() { var val = this.value; total += val=="" || isNaN(val)?0:parseInt(val); });`

Comment: @mplungjan. Yes you are wright. I have tried your way.i didn't succeed

Comment: @krishna works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/j5fjys36/

Comment: @mplugjan. Hi thanks for your time. I have one extra field so i can delete complete row . so according to number of rows summation should update . Please check these format. so i can add or remove rows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494914/how-to-do-summation-of-product-of-two-input-values-from-a-clone-table-input-valu/44495117#44495117

Answer (score 1):

This works - note the keyup and the loop over .subTotal every time, not just first time

I have cleaned the code and use the HTML from your other question

```js
function totalIt() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".subtotal").each(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    total += val == "" || isNaN(val) ? 0 : parseInt(val);
  });
  $("#total").val(total);
}
$(function() {
  var $to_clone = $('.tr_clone').first().clone();

  $("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $to_clone.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
  });
  $("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_remove', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    if ($tr.index() > 1) $tr.remove(); // leave the first
    totalIt();
  });

  $(document).on("keyup", ".quantity, .price", function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
      prce = parseInt($row.find('.price').val()),
      qnty = parseInt($row.find('.quantity').val()),
      subTotal = prce * qnty;
    $row.find('.subtotal').val(isNaN(subTotal) ? 0 : subTotal);
    totalIt()
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>U$ Price</th>
      <th>Subtotal</th>
      <th>Add</th>
      <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
      <td>
        <select style="width:200px" name="itens[]">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Item A</option>
        <option value="2">Item B</option>
        <option value="3">Item C</option>
    </td>                                            
    <td><input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" name="qtd" class="quantity text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="price" class="price text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="subtotal" class="subtotal text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" class="tr_clone_remove"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="text" readonly id="total" />
```

Comment: @mplugjan. Hi thanks for your time. I have one extra field so i can delete complete row . so according to number of rows summation should update . Please check these format. so i can add or remove rows.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494914/how-to-do-summation-of-product-of-two-input-values-from-a-clone-table-input-valu/44495117#44495117

Comment: @mplungjain. The same function not working for this

Comment: Using the HTML from your other question

Comment: Can you please check this code once it not working https://jsfiddle.net/jvk3/6ath5vy9/4/

Comment: Does not work in what way? Works for me in Chrome

Comment: The summation of id totalamnt not working. in this function. I have done according to  your method

Comment: tamnt needs to be a CLASS not ID - IDs must be unique. https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/10odkwLq/ - next time FORK my fiddle instead of updating it

Comment: Also I see no typescript and I changed ondomready to head

Comment: Thanks for your help. if i have queries regarding jquery, javascript can i approach you or not. can you please tell me

Comment: Sure. no problem...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help